# Yellow/Orange Fungus on Oak Tree

Tags: species-identification, mycology

What is the fungus pictured below? The photo was taken October 6, 2013 near San Antonio, TX.

I have Googled it and my results suggest Laetiporus root rot (*Laetiporus sulfureus*).

According to [this website](http://extension.psu.edu/pests/plant-diseases/all-fact-sheets/oak-diseases) the presence of this fungus indicates the tree should be removed.

Is there any chance that this is something else? I would hate to remove such a beautiful oak tree.

[image: Unknown Fungus on Oak Tree]

Comment: Please mention when and where the picture was taken. Also ask around you neighborhood in case anyone is missing a brain, just in case ;).

Comment: Any chance we can get a closer shot of the section attached to the tree?  Regarding felling the tree, is it at risk of hitting a tree should it come down? From the photo it looks like it's pretty open.  You can also anchor trees with cables so that should they fall, it would be away from structures.

Comment: @losthorse please [edit] your question to add exra information rather than put it in the comments where it is easily overlooked.

Comment: @AtlLED - Unfortunately, I have already removed the fungus. It does not seem to be at risk of hitting another tree should it fall, but I would have to take a closer look to be sure.

Comment: @losthorse Well if it's not in danger of hitting anything, there is very little reason to fell it.  If nature wants to bring it down, it will.  More to the point, I question Laetiporus sulfureus id.  You normally see much clearer shelving with that, or at least all the ones I ate growing up did.  Do you live in the Rockies?

Comment: @AtlLED - thanks for the input and perspective... the tree is in south central Texas.

Comment: @losthorse If you took down the fungus, can you give us any more details on it?  Was it hard, slimy, smelly, or brittle?  Did it have gills/fins on the back towards the tree.  Does the tree show any of the other signs of heart rot?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure but it looks like a species of the Laetiporus mushrooms. Please refer to its [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laetiporus) page for the full info.

**edit:** I did not read your question fully and now I see that you reached the same conclusion. Just ignore my answer. As to the second part of your question asking if it could be anything else, that is quite hard to visually determine as there are many look alikes in the mushroom kingdom. [Read this](http://www.first-nature.com/fungi/facts/imposters.php) for some imposters.